# issues with the Geolocator xamarin plugin by James Montemagno

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a app in xamarin forms that needs to take the gps location and combine the latitude and longitude into a url for forcast.io i'm using the Geolocator plugin by James Montemagno and followed the readme but i'm still getting these errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'msi'
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator' to
>   'Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'CrossGeolocator' does not contain a definition for
>   'IsGeolocationEnabled' and no extension method 'IsGeolocationEnabled'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'CrossGeolocator' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'CrossGeolocator' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetPositionAsync' and no extension method 'GetPositionAsync'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'CrossGeolocator' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'CrossGeolocator' does not contain a definition for
>   'DesiredAccuracy' and no extension method 'DesiredAccuracy' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'CrossGeolocator' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and then here's the radar code:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Plugin.Geolocator;

namespace AppName.Radar
{
    public interface MyLocationTracker
    {
        void ObtainMyLocation();
        event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> locationObtained;    
    }

    public interface MyLocationEventArgs
    {
        double lat { get; set; }
        double lng { get; set; }
    }  

    public partial class RadarHome : ContentPage
    {    
        private readonly CrossGeolocator _locator;
        private double BetaLat;
        private double BetaLog;

        public RadarHome()
        {
            MyLocationTracker msi;

            _locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            if (_locator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
            {   
                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                {                    

                    msi.locationObtained += (object Esender, MyLocationEventArgs ew) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ew.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();  
                }

                else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                {
                    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();
                    msi.locationObtained += (object Jsender, MyLocationEventArgs je) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(je.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();
                }
            }

            _locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            GetPositionAsynchronously();

            string str = string.Format(
                "https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/Lat:{0} , Long: {1}", BetaLat, BetaLog);

            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(str);
        }

        private async void GetPositionAsynchronously()
        {
            //will run asynchronously in a diff thread
            var position = await _locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);

            BetaLat = position.Latitude; //will work
            BetaLog = position.Longitude; // will work      
        }    
    }
}
```

I have the latest Geolocator nuget package installed on all 3 platforms (Froms, iOS, Android) I am using VS2015 update 3 and am still learning xamrarin forms so I'm sorry for asking such a noob question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{       
    //You missed to resolve plugin there
    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();

    msi.locationObtained += (object Esender, MyLocationEventArgs ew) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ew.lat);
    };
    msi.ObtainMyLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your _locator definition should look like this

`private readonly IGeolocator _locator;`

Answer (score 0):

So both @William Corncob Decker, and @Greensy answers were correct

_locator definition needs to be: `private readonly IGeolocator _locator;`

and I did miss to resolve the msi plugin heres that code:

```cs
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{
    //You missed to resolve plugin there
    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();

    msi.locationObtained += (object Esender, MyLocationEventArgs ew) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ew.lat);
    };
    msi.ObtainMyLocation();
}
```

The only reason I'm doing this is because I can't mark both William Corncob Decker, and Greensy answers as correct so full credit goes to both of them!

Thank you guys again!